# JS, using foo.exports to return an array to share across different pages

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two js files in my node.js app using socket.io also and I need to share an array between the two files, I am using JS exports like so:

```
foo.exports = function(){
    return usernames
}
```

This works great if the array has values, if the array is empty it doesn't return an empty array it returns an error in my terminal:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'rooms'
```

In the file that this error occurs I include the JS array like so:

```
var chat = require('./index.js')
chat.rooms()
```

Now, my thinking was that because the array is empty JS doesn't recognize an empty function as a function at all, so I tried something like the below code to make the usernames array always have a value (if empty, push 'empty' into array). Then I could do a check for the value 'empty' in the array:

But I still get the same error...

```
if(usernames.length > 0){
    return usernames;
    console.log('usernames has values');
} else {
    console.log('empty usernames array');
    return usernames.push('empty');
}
```

Regards

Comment: `The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.`. By using `return ..push(..` you're returning 1, not an array.

Comment: ahah! Perfect! Thanks artm!

Comment: No worries. Good to know your theory was correct.